# vba code to find img title from webpage to excel using selenium vba

Tags: vba, selenium, firefox

I am trying to find img title from webpage to excel using selenium vba below is the vba code which i am using but not getting any result and also below are the image of banks whose data i want in excel sheet.
Request you to please help me.

```html
Sub Class_Initialize()
Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.FirefoxDriver")
driver.get "https://www.99acres.com/supertech-cape-town-sector-74-noida-npxid-r922?sid=UiB8IFFTIHwgUyB8IzMxIyAgfCAxIHwgNyM0MyMgfCA4MjEyIHwjNSMgIHwg"
driver.Window.Maximize
Dim dd As Variant
dd = driver.findElementByClass("bankBodr bankTuple").Text
Range("A1") = dd
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will lead you to fetch the content. Turn out that the items you are after are not visible until you scroll the browser downward. So I've used a javascript code to let the browser scroll to the bottom so that the items can be visualized.

```
Sub Get_Titles()
    Dim post As Object

    With CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
        .get "https://www.99acres.com/supertech-cape-town-sector-74-noida-npxid-r922?sid=UiB8IFFTIHwgUyB8IzMxIyAgfCAxIHwgNyM0MyMgfCA4MjEyIHwjNSMgIHwg"
        .ExecuteScript ("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        .Wait 500
        For Each post In .FindElementsByCss("#carousel img")
            r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = post.Attribute("title")
        Next post
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Output:

```
LIC Housing Finance Ltd.
AXIS Bank LTD.
IDBI Bank Ltd.
Corporation Bank
HDFC home loans
```

Btw, change the portion within `CreateObject("")` to fit for your driver.